# HTML gets parsed poorly

Tags: html, laravel, anchor, blockquote

My HTML somehow gets messed up after being parsed by the browser.

This is my input:

```
 <a href="/quotes/{{ $quote->id }}" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit; display: block">
     <blockquote>
         <p id="quote-{{ $quote->id }}-text">{{ $quote->quote }}</p>

         <small class="author" id="quote-{{ $quote->id }}-author">
             <a href="/authors/{{ $quote->author->username }}">{{ $quote->author->name }}</a>
         </small>
     </blockquote>
 </a>
```

And this is the output I get from Chrome dev tools:

```
    <body>
<a href="/quotes/{{ $quote->id }}" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit; display: block">
         </a> <!-- Why is it closing this tag over here? -->
    <blockquote><a href="/quotes/{{ $quote->id }}" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit; display: block">
             <p id="quote-{{ $quote->id }}-text">{{ $quote->quote }}</p>

             <small class="author" id="quote-{{ $quote->id }}-author">
                 </small></a><small class="author" id="quote-{{ $quote->id }}-author"><a href="/authors/{{ $quote->author->username }}">{{ $quote->author->name }}</a>
             </small>
         </blockquote>
     </body>
```

The problem is the browser closes the `a` tag when parsing the html, I think, and the `blockquote` is not wrapped by `a` anymore. How can I wrap the `blockquote` in an `a` tag?

Thank you!

Comment: That's not right semantics also look you have an anchor within an anchor. That's why it's messed up as well as the block quote that has a paragraph tag within it. So you not know how to write proper html??? Asking because tags have an actual role!

Comment: Well, I'm not a html expert but that's kind of what I wanted to make. A `blockquote` that is clickable and the author to be wrapped by an `a` tag too. Any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yah, you're right. The a tag (is an inline-tag) can not contain the blockquote tag (is a block-level tag). So, I think it's impossible if you want to wrap the blockquote in the a tag.

Take a look at this rule: [Block-Level tags versus Inline tags](http://www.yorku.ca/nmw/facs1939f13/week01/xhtml_inlineVSblock.html)

> 1. Block-level tags can contain Inline tags.
> 2. The reverse is not true -- **inline tags cannot contain block-level tags**.
> 3. Some block-level elements can contain some other block-level elements.

---

Or maybe you can use javascript **onclick** event to redirect:

```
<blockquote onclick="window.open('/quotes/{{ $quote->id }}')">
     <p id="quote-{{ $quote->id }}-text">{{ $quote->quote }}</p>

     <small class="author" id="quote-{{ $quote->id }}-author">
         <a href="/authors/{{ $quote->author->username }}">{{ $quote->author->name }}</a>
     </small>
 </blockquote>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great idea.. I adapted it a little bit to this:

`<blockquote onclick="window.location = '/quotes/{{ $quote->id }}';" style="cursor: pointer">` so now it's more like an `anchor`